Question about the structure of mathematical induction
I'm studying proof by mathematical induction, and I have a question about the step where you demonstrate that a predicate $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)$. Consider the following generalized example:
Prove or disprove: $\forall n \in \mathbb N \, \Big(P(n)\Big)$.
Step 1: I show $P(1) \equiv True$.
Step 2: I must demonstrate that $\forall n \in \mathbb N \, \Big(P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)\Big)$.
Here's where I get confused. My professor told me that in order to demonstrate this, I assume that for any arbitrary n, $P(n)$ is true. Then I show that $P(n+1)$ logically follows from assuming $P(n)$.
However, if I assume $P(n)$ is true, am I not also assuming $P(n+1)$ is true automatically? Since $(n+1) \in \mathbb{N}$, n+1 is a natural number, and I've already assumed that for any arbitrary natural number, P(n) is true.
If I instead start by assuming that for a specific n, P(n) is true, then the principle of mathematical induction does not prove the original statement because that specific n might by n = 6 in which case P(2), P(3), P(4), P(5) might not be true and I've only proved the proposition for n = 1 and n >= 6, not for all n.

I know there is a flaw in my reasoning here somewhere, appreciate the help!

"Arbitrary" is not a good word here.  Does it make sense to you if we assume P(n) is true for a particular (but unspecified) n?  This is really not very different from the following proof structure which you have probably seen.  Theorem.  If n is even then so is n^2.  Proof.  Assume n is even... then n^2 is even.

The order is this: You pick an arbitrary $n$, then you assume that $P(n)$ is true for this specific $n$, and then you must show that $P(n+1)$ is true. And this must work for any choice of $n$.

What you're arguing is that $(\forall n. P(n)) \to (\forall n. P(n+1))$, but this doesn't entail $\forall n. (P(n) \to P(n+1))$. The difference is important.

See this similar post as well as this one

To begin with, here's how the induction step should go:
We want to show that $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})[P(n)\implies P(n+1)]$.
To do this, we pick, arbitrarily, a member $n$ of $\mathbb{N}$.
We assume $P(n)$ holds. Then, on the basis of our argument (which depends on what $P(n)$ actually is), we show that $P(n+1)$ must also hold.
Thus, we have shown that regardless of what natural number $n$ actually is (since we chose it arbitrarily), $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$. Thus, $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})[P(n)\implies P(n+1)]$.
Now, your confusion arises from

My professor told me that in order to demonstrate this, I assume that for any arbitrary n, P(n) is true.

By this, your professor didn't mean for you to assume $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})P(n)$, which would be assuming the very theorem you want to prove; rather, it was them wanting you to pick any natural number, chosen arbitrarily, call it $n$, and assume $P(n)$ is true for this $n$. At which point, the above argument can be used to complete the proof.

If I instead start by assuming that for a specific n, P(n) is true, then the principle of mathematical induction does not prove the original statement because that specific n might by n = 6 in which case P(2), P(3), P(4), P(5) might not be true and I've only proved the proposition for n = 1 and n >= 6, not for all n.

Assuming $P(n)$ for a specific $n$ would mean picking a fixed number like $5$ and assuming $P(5)$. In which case showing $P(n+1)$ would just prove $P(5)\implies P(6)$ and nothing else. Instead, you are meant to assume $P(n)$ for a particular but unspecified $n$, and show $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})[P(n)\implies P(n+1)]$. The idea is, since we know $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ for any $n$,
that means $P(1) \implies P(2)$ and $P(2) \implies P(3)$, and so on; as long as we know $P(1)$ is true, the chain of implications guarantees $P(n)$ for every other $n$.

I think this helps. I'm still hung up on the correct language to use but here's how I understand it. If I assume P(n) is true for any arbitrary n, then I've just assumed the proposition is true, namely that $\forall n \in \mathbb N [P(n)]$. However, if I assume P(n) is true for an arbitrary n, then I have not assumed that $\forall n \in \mathbb N [P(n)]$ is true. I feel the any vs an distinction is key here.

As an example, I use $(\forall x \in \mathbb Z) , [\sqrt{x} \text{ is real}]$. $\sqrt{x}$ is clearly not real for all integers, but the induction hypothesis  $(\forall x \in \mathbb Z) , [\sqrt{x} \text{ is real } \Rightarrow \sqrt{x+1} \text{ is real}]$ is true. The base case I choose is critical here; I can prove the predicate is true for all x >=0, but the predicate is false otherwise.

Actually, in step $2$ you show that if $P(n)$ is true for any fix $n$ then it is true for the natural number that follow $n$ which it is $n+1$. Here $n$ is an arbitrary fix natural number. So because you have proved that it is true for $n=1$ (in step $1$) then it is true for $1+1=2$.
Now, we know that $P(n)$ is true for $n=2$ so it is true for $2+1=3$ (Because we have proved step $2$).
Again, because it is true for  $n=3$ so it is true for $3+1=4$
If we continue this, then  $P(n)$ is true for all the natural numbers.
